# Derivation of third-order Rusanov method for linear convection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, hyperbolic-equations

I've been wrestling for a number of days with the following scheme of the one dimensional first-order hyperbolic linear convection equation,

$$
u_t+cu_x=0
$$

Introduce a set of points $x_j = jh$ for $j = 0,1,\dots, N$ with $h = 1/N$, and $t_n = nk$ for $n = 0,1,\dots, M$. We introduce also
$x_{j+1 / 2}=x_{j}+\frac{h}{2}$, $t_{n+1 / 2}=t_{n}+\frac{k}{2}$, and denote $v= ck/h$.
The numerical method has three steps:

Step 1: $u_{j+1 / 2}^{(1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(u_{j+1}^{n}+u_{j}^{n}\right)-\frac{1}{3} v\left(u_{j+1}^{n}-u_{j}^{n}\right)$

Step 2: $u_{j}^{(2)}=u_{j}^{n}-\frac{2}{3} v\left(u_{j+1 / 2}^{(1)}-u_{j-1 / 2}^{(1)}\right)$

Step 3: $u_{j}^{n+1}=u_{j}^{n}- \frac{v}{24}\left(-2 u_{j+2}^{n}+7 u_{j+1}^{n}-7 u_{j-1}^{n}+2 u_{j-2}^{n}\right) -\frac{3}{8} v\left(u_{j+1}^{(2)}-u_{j-1}^{(2)}\right) -\frac{\omega}{24}\left(u_{j+2}^{n}-4 u_{j+1}^{n}+6 u_{j}^{n}-4 u_{j-1}^{n}+u_{j-2}^{n}\right)
$

According to [these notes](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~twhsheu/course/Finite%20difference/NUMER2+3.pdf) and [this paper](https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0469%281974%29031%3C1500%3AACONSO%3E2.0.CO%3B2), it's called the third-order Rusanov method (Burstein-Mirin). The parameter $\omega$ is added for stability purposes, which is ensured if $|v|\leq 1$ and $4v^2-v^4\leq\omega<3$.

Please, how I can derive this scheme using a finite difference method?
I'm in need of a nudge in the right direction

Comment: I don't have any idea about how $\omega$ appeared in the scheme

Comment: From this reference, it's called Rusanov (Burstein-Mirin)method
http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~twhsheu/course/Finite%20difference/NUMER2+3.pdf
you can take a look here too

https://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/pdf/10.1175/1520-0469%281974%29031%3C1500%3AACONSO%3E2.0.CO%3B2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme is derived in (1). For the evolution operator $u_t = F(u,x,t,u_x)$ with $F(u,x,t,u_x) = -cu_x$, the three steps correspond to the following [Runge-Kutta scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), represented by the Butcher tableau
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
0 & & \\
\tfrac13 & \tfrac13 & \\
\tfrac23 & 0 & \tfrac23 \\
\hline
& \tfrac14 & 0 & \tfrac34
\end{array}
$$
(third-order Heun's method).
The operator $F$ is evaluated by using appropriate centered finite differences, and third-order accuracy is satisfied. The term with coefficient $\omega$ -- added for stability reasons -- is a fourth-order-accurate finite difference (see articles for details).

---

(1) Burstein, S. Z., & Mirin, A. A. (1970). Third order difference methods for hyperbolic equations. *J. Comput. Phys.* 5(3), 547–571. [doi:10.1016/0021-9991(70)90080-x](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(70)90080-x)

(2) Rusanov, V. (1970). On difference schemes of third order accuracy for nonlinear hyperbolic systems. *J. Comput. Phys.* 5(3), 507–516. [doi:10.1016/0021-9991(70)90077-x](https://10.1016/0021-9991(70)90077-x)

Comment: No, the RK scheme in time direction is Heun's 3rd order method \begin{array}{l|lll}
0&\\
\frac13&\frac13\\
\frac23&0&\frac23\\
\hline
&\frac14&0&\frac34
\end{array}, not the RK3 method of Kutta. This is also mentioned in the paper cited in the question.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for the catch -- I should have read the paper more carefully. Answer under updating process.

Comment: LutzLehmann and Harry49, both of you, are a real inspiration for me in Mathematics, Thank you for all your efforts and your contributions to help us to learn and progress.
Big Thanks

Comment: I have a new question, please, I need to read more about the method used in (1)  $u^{(r)}=u^{(0)}+\Delta t \sum_{s=0}^{r-1} \alpha_{r s} F\left(t_{s}, u^{(s)}\right), \quad r=1,2, \dots, R$, because I have a difficulty to compared with [Runge-Kutta scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), since in the $k_r$ expression we don't use  $u^{(0)}$ in each iteration, do you know what is called ?

Comment: @Almendrof66 It still looks like Runge-Kutta. As specified on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge–Kutta_methods), *the above equations may have different but equivalent definitions in some texts*

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you!